# How to read Environment Variables in a PowerApp?

Tags: powerapps

I'm looking for a quick example of how to read an Environment Variable in a PowerApp. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/environmentvariables

I've set the variable in my environment. How do I simply read that in a PowerApp and display the current value in a text label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps to solve this:

1. Add the "Environment Variables Values" CDS Entity to you App's data source
2. Set the value of the text of the label to be:

   LookUp('Environment Variable Values', 'Environment Variable Definition'.'Schema Name' = "test_environment_data").Value

Source of the solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxjwpqcwI_Y